# How to get atributes and operator from function

Tags: python

Is there any way how to extraxt values like:

```
['TAG1'], [==], [100]
```

from function:

```
verify_state('TAG1') == 100)
```

inside this function, or in decorated function?

Let me show what I mean:

```
# decorator func
def printer(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    # wrapper
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        print ('Verify that tag {0} {1} {2}'.format(value1, operator, value2))
        # output will be like:
        # Verify that tag TAG1 == 100

        # No we have to call func, that will get information about value of TAG1
        # will be for example 115.5
        value1 = get_tag_value('TAG1')

        # and now compare results
        # compare(value1 [operator] value2)
        # in this case:
        # compare(115.5 == 100)
        # which will fail, but that not that important.
        return result
    return wrapper

@printer
def a(x):
    return x
```

At the end, I would like to call this functions:

```
a(('TAG1') == 100)
```

Is it possible somehow?

I found out that there is hidden function as `__eq__` for 'equal' etc that can be re-coded by me,
but this not what I need. I don't need to "re-invent a bike while it's already invented" If you know what I mean..

I only need to extract those values, print them into log, and then proceed the function (`a()`) like there wouldnt be any necessary print.

Comment: ...what? Could you show how this would be used, e.g. mock up a console session? What should happen when you call `a(('TAG1') == 100)` (and why the extra parentheses)?

Comment: `verify_state('TAG1') == 100` is an expression, not a function. All you can "extract" in a decorator around `verify_state` is the argument (here 'TAG1'). 

The only way to get what you want using decorators would be to pass the args, test operator and test value to the function, ie you'd need to have _all_ your calls going like `verify_state("TAG1", operators.eq, 100)`, which might be rather impractical.

TL;DR : what's your real use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that what you want is something like, having decorated `verify_state`:

```
>>> verify_state('TAG1') == 100
Verify that tag 'TAG1' == 100
True # or False or whatever
```

In that case, the short answer is **no**. `verify_state` knows nothing about what will be done with the value it returns, a decorator will only have access to `'TAG1'`.

---

Alternatively, if you meant something like an additional function:

```
>>> some_func(verify_state('TAG1') == 100)
Verify that tag 'TAG1' == 100
True # or False or whatever
```

Then the answer is still **no** because the order of operations is effectively:

```
>>> arg = verify_state('TAG1') == 100
>>> some_func(arg)
```

i.e. the expression is evaluated prior to calling the function.

---

What you **could** do, however, is have something like:

```
>>> import operator # get access to operators
>>> PLAINTEXT = {operator.eq: "=="} # map operators to text
>>> def printer(val1, op, val2): # new function to print and evaluate
        print("Verify that {!r} {} {!r}".format(val1, PLAINTEXT[op], val2))
        return op(val1, val2)

>>> printer(42, operator.eq, 'foo')
Verify that 42 == 'foo'
False
```

---

However, again, if you called e.g. `printer(verify_state('TAG1'), operator.eq, 100)`, the call to `verify_state` would be evaluated **before** calling `printer`, so you would end up with e.g.

```
>>> printer(verify_state('TAG1'), operator.eq, 100)
Verify that 100 == 100
True
```

which probably isn't terribly helpful.

To get around that, you could add a decorator in:

```
>>> def verbose(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Calling: {}(*{!r}, **{!r})".format(func.__name__,
                             args, kwargs))
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Call returned: {!r}".format(result))
        return result
    return wrapper

>>> @verbose
def verify_state(tag):
    return 100

>>> printer(verify_state('TAG1'), operator.eq, 100)
Calling: verify_state(*('TAG1',), **{})
Call returned: 100
Verify that 100 == 100
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the operator module https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html, then just create a function that takes your tag, operator and right hand and do your checks that way. For example,

```
import operator

def check_state(tag, operator, right_hand):
  value1 = get_value(tag)
  return operator(value1, right_hand)

check_state("Tag1", operator.eq, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks for Your advice. On one hand, this is hapefull, but on the other - I cann't use it like that. 

Problem here is, that I need use simple command like:
`a(('TAG1') == 100)`